# Firebase Cloud Functions generated page flagged with reduce server response time

Tags: firebase, handlebars.js, pug, google-cloud-functions, template-engine

I have a Firebase website project, right now everything looks good except for the Firebase Cloud Functions generated pages flagged with reduce server response time on pagespeed insights. Insights would result **`0.5 - 1.5`** seconds.

Static pages get a score of **`99`** on mobile and **`86`** on desktop. With the cloud functions generated pages however the highest I get for mobile is **`75`** and lowest drops to as low as **`30`**.

Here is some background on what is happening:

- The page being requested is identified to ready the values needed for the Firestore queries.
- 4 Firestore queries (3 collections with <100 documents and 1 with <5000 documents, which are very small).
- Data from the queries are organized and prepped for render.
- Page renders with **`res.render()`**

**Original Build:**

- Cloud Functions
- Express
- Cors
- Handlebars (as the template engine)

This build would usually get me a score of **`60-75`**. Server response time is still high but it is consistent within the range **`0.5 - 1.5`**

**Alternative Build:**

This build I use the same code for the queries except for the template engine rendering step.

- Cloud Functions
- Express
- Cors
- PUG (as the template engine)

This build gives both the best and the worst scores. I don't get a medium score on this of **`60-75`**, The highest I got is a perfect **`100`** and the lowest is a very low **`30`**. The bad thing about this is that it is very inconsistent and I can't determine the reason.

**Is it a Cold Start problem?**

I have read about cold start so I tried experimenting if it was the problem.

**First Attempt**
I made a function that would ping the functions used by my Cloud Functions. I started it up and put it on a loop every 10seconds on my desktop. After a few minutes I checked Pagespeed if it had any effects, no improvements.

**Second Attempt**
I made a function that would fetch the page I am testing on Pagespeed. I started it up and put it on a loop also on my desktop. I checked Pagespeed and it also did not have any effects.

So I guess I should cross out the **`Cold Start`** issue? Or am I handling the cold start issue wrong? Or maybe its a templating thing since using two different template engines have different results?

Anyway, this is what I have done so far, any idea on how to reduce the server response time of Firebase Cloud Functions generated pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cold start might be your problem.

If you keep one Cloud Function warm it will keep a container with that function warm - so that the next user can come and use the function in a warm state.

However - if you have multiple users attempting to use the cloud function it will allocate one warm container to a connection, then another couple of cold containers to the other users. It's how they scale - building out more containers.

I'm assuming whats happening is your tests are sometimes connecting to the warmed container - and when they are in use the tests are having to wait for a cold start on the other containers.

Read up on [Cold Starts](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#cold_starts)

> A new function instance is started in two cases:
>
> When a new function instance is automatically created to scale up to the load, or occasionally to replace an existing instance.

Comment: so wouldn't requesting the page consistently (my second attempt in solving cold start) technically help warm up the functions? Do I need to maintain it for long periods to get actual results?

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#concurrency) as well. If you're warming up the function it's keeping it warm for next user - I'm not sure how the speed test works - if it makes multiple requests to the page then it could use the warmed up function for the first request, then cold functions for the subsequent requests.

Comment: Also while keeping it warm - if a user attempts to connect to the function at the same time it's being used (To keep warm) then cloud functions will have to build a cold container for that request. So you could have a clash between your scheduled task and your tests.

Function stay warm for around 20 minutes AFAIK so try slowing down your warmup requests.

Comment: thanks for the very helpful information, i'll read up some more on the subject.

Comment: Come back with your findings.

Comment: yeah I made a few tests, tried to simmulate a "multiple users" test on my "alternative build", so far the results do show a cold start behavior which explains why pagespeed would have very high scores and then suddenly drops, but I can't balance it right now since the site still has low traffic. Thanks for the info, really helped.